# How to iterate through list elements in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am unable to figure out how to iterate through the rendered List in React Js and access the key and value properties.

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPR5v.png)

```
const Cards = ({arr}) => {
  return (
    <ul className='output'>
      {arr.map(e => {
        return <li key={e.id} className="card" >
          {e.value}
          <FaTimes color='red' style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={e => console.log(e.value)}/>
        </li>
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Clicking the icon `<FaTimes color='red' ... />` should log the value of `key` to the console, but instead it is returning `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onClick` handlers will receive the mouse event as a parameter. So the `e` you pass to that is a different `e` than the one you use in your iteration.

Use

```
onClick={() => console.log(e.value)}
```

and it will work.

---

Or just use a different name to avoid the [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

```
onClick={(event) => console.log(e.value)}
```

Comment: Now it remains how to iterate through the <ul>/<li> elements

Comment: @Lexzee what do you mean ? Your code should iterate over the `arr` and create equal number of `li` elements.

Comment: By clicking the icon  I wish to iterate over the `<ul>`  element. I'm also unable to get the value of `key`

Comment: @Lexzee You have an icon for each `li` element. What exactly do you want to do when you click on it ? Also to get the relevant `key` you should log the `e.id` which you use for the key as well.

Comment: When I click on it, i want to be able to loop through all the rendered `li`.